# Zoom and pan an image using jQuery's mousemove event on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve the goal simulated in this video. How to achieve this on mouseover.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7OTdkCA_2dNUGhtMlgtZ0s2dlU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

just googled "jquery zoom plugins" and found:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/
git: https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/
try to manipulate this plugin to your needs.